# Export Java VM Args in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

for my Java Program I want to export the VM args like xmx and xms.
If I enter the args in Eclipse
Run --> Run Configurations --> MyProgram --> VM arguments

it works but if I export the program it does not work.

If I start my program with a BAT file

```java
java -Xmx512M -Xms250M -jar Datei.jar
PAUSE
```

it also works but I want to avoid this.

So how can export these arguments to my JAR file ?

Comment: You cannot. They must be given on the `java` command line, so they cannot be part of the jar file itself. Shipping the jar file together with a .bat or .sh file would be the way to help the user, so you're already doing it.

Comment: Thx for your answer. That is bad because the BAT window always stays open. If I close the BAT window it will also close the Java program.

Maybe I can try to rework the code and use an other JSON library than 
org.json.JSONArray because its an array of around 60.000 objects

Comment: So write `start java ...` and remove the `pause`. Or better yet, assuming the java program is a GUI program, use `javaw ...` and still remove that `pause`

Comment: javaw did the trick :) 
thx a lot